# c++ replacing order of items in byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, replace, find

I'm writing a code for Arduino C++.

I have a byte array with hex byte values, for example:

```
20 32 36 20 E0 EC 20 F9 F0 E9 E9 E3 F8 5C 70 5C 70 5C 73 20 E3 E2 EC 20 F8 E0 E5 E1 EF 20 39 31 5C
```

There are four ASCII digits in these bytes:

HEX 0x32 is number 2 in ascii code

HEX 0x35 is number 5 in ascii code

HEX 0x39 is number 9 in ascii code

and so on....

https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp862.html

So the hex values 32, 36 represent the number 26, and 39, 31 represent 91.

I want to find these numbers and reverse each group, so that (in this example) 62 and 19 are represented instead of 26 and 91.

The output would thus have to look like this:

```
20 36 32 20 E0 EC 20 F9 F0 E9 E9 E3 F8 5C 70 5C 70 5C 73 20 E3 E2 EC 20 F8 E0 E5 E1 EF 20 31 39 5C
```

**The numbers don't have to be two digits but could be anything in 0-1000**

I also know that each group of such numbers is preceded by the hex value `20`, if that helps.

I have done this in C# (with some help of Stack overflow users :-) ):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(HexMessage1,
                           @"(?<=20\-)3[0-9](\-3[0-9])*(?=\-20)",
                           match => string.Join("-", Transform(match.Value.Split('-'))));

 private static IEnumerable<string> Transform(string[] items)
        {
            // Either terse Linq:
            // return items.Reverse();

            // Or good old for loop:
            string[] result = new string[items.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; ++i)
                result[i] = items[items.Length - i - 1];

            return result;
        }
```

Can someone help me make it work on C++?

Comment: *"32,36 witch is 26"* You mean you want to replace `3X 3Y` by `3Y 3X` (when X, Y are digits) ? How about `31 32 33` ?

Comment: It is still extremely unclear what "I have 4 digits (numbers) inside" means. I see the following numbers: `26 32 36 20 20 70 70 73 20 20 29 39 31`. Your C# regex indicates that you are only interested in numbers starting with `3`. Please say this in the question if that's the case.

Comment: i need to find all numbers . and repalce them 28--82 , 1234--4321 1957-7591 , in Hex the numbers are represent as 30-39

Comment: You mean the **digits** are represented as 30-39? Please don't mix up "number" and "digit", it is really confusing.

Comment: The way I understand your question is _"in this sequence of bytes, there are groups of bytes starting with `0x20`, followed by a series of digits in ASCII (`0x30` to `0x39`). In each of these groups, I want to reverse the order of the digits"_. Is this correct?

Comment: yes , this is in better English them mine - but yes:-)

Comment: By the way, it seem that the "byte array" isn't really an array of bytes (in the sense it contains `0x20`, `0x31` etc.), but rather it's a space-delimited *string*, where each "byte" is two digit characters representing a hexadecimal value? That also makes it very different.

Comment: As for a possible solution, why not create an *actual* "byte array", using a `std::vector<uint8_t>`, and then use some kind of pattern matching to find the byte-sequences you want to reverse? The actual reversing is easy if you have two iterators (to the first and last element in the sequence), as all you need is to call [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) with those iterators. Recreating the string from the vector is also trivial once you've processed it.

Comment: can you show me how to do this? I'm new at arduino c++ . I only know the basic .

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array, element by element, looking for `0x32` or `0x39`. If found, check the next byte (if within bounds) to see if it matches `0x36` or `0x31` (respectively). If it does then swap the current and the next byte. Continue the loop, skipping over the current *and* the next byte.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I want to do ... I don't know what the number will be in the array . not just 32 or 39... it could be any number and also could be 3-4 digits number

Comment: @David12123 Then please edit your question to improve it. I recommend that you take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us what you have tried (and include the expected and actual output for some specified input).

Comment: this is what I wrote at the post - and also mention "EXAMPLE" , and gave what I have now and what I need to have . please read my post and see. tell me what isn't understood -(i don't see the problem in the post)